# Laravel relationship manytomany paginate issue

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have 3 tables / models

```
User (has an id)
Articles (has an id )
UserArticles (has an id, article_id and user_id)
```

I am a little confused on how I would set up the relationship so that I will be able to get all articles connected to a user so I can set up a call like so in my controller:

```
$articles = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->articles->paginate(20);
```

I figured this was a manytomany relationship so I am playing around with this code inside the User model:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', 'user_saved_articles', 'user_id', 'article_id');
}
```

Now this works, as long as I don't call paginate() on the controller function I'd like to use above. Here is where my real issue lies now, so it works with

```
$articles = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->articles;
```

but with this:

```
$articles = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->articles->paginate(20);
```

it comes up with the error:

```
FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 217:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()
```

I can't figure out why I can't paginate on this, as I can with all my other queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call an eloquent relation as an attribute `User::find(Auth::user()->id)->articles` it will automatically execute the SQL, and return a Collection. The error is telling you that you have a Collection, which you can't call paginate() on.

If you want to reference the relationship to add more statements you need to call it as a function `User::find(Auth::user()->id)->articles()`. This will return a QueryBuilder instance that you can add statements to, and/or paginate.

So this should work:

```
$articles = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->articles()->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Thanks, was also answered on Reddit, this is the correct answer and it works.